# Seeking clarification regarding type erasure and type inference

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

```
class Undoable<T> {
  T value;
  Deque<Object> history;
      
  Undoable(T t, Deque<Object> history) {
    this.value = t;
    this.history = history;
  }
  
  static <T> Undoable<T> of(T t) {
    return new Undoable<T>(t, new LinkedList<Object>());
  }

  public <R> Undoable<R> flatMap(Function<T, Undoable<R>> mapper) {
    Undoable<R> r = mapper.apply(value);
    Deque<Object> newHistory = new LinkedList<>();
    newHistory.addAll(history);
    newHistory.addAll(r.history);
    return new Undoable<R>(r.value, newHistory);
  }

  public <R> Undoable<R> undo() {
    Deque<Object> newHistory = new LinkedList<>(this.history);
    R r;
    try {
      r = (R)newHistory.removeLast(); //line A
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      throw new CannotUndoException();
    }
    return new Undoable<R>(r, newHistory);
  }
}
```

Given the code snippet above, let say we leave Line A as it is and ignore the compilation warning. What would happen if we

```
Undoable<Integer> i = Undoable.of("hello").flatMap(s -> {
    Deque<Object> history;
    history = new LinkedList<>();
    history.add(s);
    return new Undoable<Integer>(s.length(), history);
});
Undoable<Double> d = i.undo();
```

I get that `Undoable<Integer>` and `Undoable<Double>` erases to `Undoable`. But what does `R` in the `undo()` method become? Does it infer to be `Double` since `Double` is the target type of that method call?

I've tried running the code on my machine and it runs fine but I have no idea why. Can anyone shed some light? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Since what I can understand, yes, it will be cast from Integer to Double, try declaring the d variable with something different, to see it will throws an error.

Comment: Right, the other question was a more general variation of this question. I was confused about how type inference and type erasure worked. Initially, what I thought was that since R is inferred to be Double, why wouldn't it throw a ClassCastException. I suspected that R ended up being erased to Object but that didn't really make sense because why would R erase to Object if R was already being inferred to be Double. Now that you and Wasserman cleared things up, I realised that R is still erased to Object and that inference is lost after checking that it is type-safe.

Comment: Glad that helped, but please really test it with something that throws a cast exception, i’m curious now, try change the Double to something absurd like InputStream or something like that.

Comment: I'll only get a ClassCastException if I take its value out and operate on it. I'm sorry I am still rather new to Java so I have no idea how the InputStream type works. But to put it into context, I will get a ClassCastException if I do something like ```System.out.println(d.value/2);```. It only when we operate on it that Java realises it doesn't match. I hope I demonstrated what you were looking for hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

The `R` type it will become `Object`, even when inferred during the method call, this is because of `R` been of no use, since you never explicit declared it, like this `i.<Double>undo()`, in most use cases, parametric types are used in methods to infer the types of the method parameters. About your code flow, even with a Undone the `d.value` is a string, it's because `d` `Undone` type will be compiled to object, since the `R` type could be anything, doesn't have how to compare, in compile time, the type inferred result of the method call with your declaration. If you put `Undone<Double> d = i.<String>undo()` it will throw an error, otherwise if you don't explicit declare, never will throw a cast exception.